# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030018 (layout/list) for fragment SampleListFragment{2a6da765 #0 id=0x7f030018}

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I'm using this library slidingmenu https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
when i want add listview into slid menu, i use this code

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.layout.list, new SampleListFragment())
            .commit();
```

but it gives me this 
exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030018 (layout/list) for fragment SampleListFragment{2a6da765 #0 id=0x7f030018}

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {
    private com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar action;
      SlidingMenu sm;
      TextView txt_1,txt_2,txt_3,txt_4,txt_5;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*SlidingMenu menu;
        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidth(100);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setBehindWidth(200);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);*/
        txt_1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
        txt_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ttkkkk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        txt_2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_2);
        txt_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ttkkkk1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        txt_3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_3);
        txt_3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ttkkkk3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        txt_4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_4);
        txt_4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ttkkkk4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        txt_5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_5);
        txt_5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ttkkkk5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

            sm =  new SlidingMenu(this);

            sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
            sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
            sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
            sm.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
            sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
            sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
            sm.setMenu(R.layout.list);

            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.layout.list, new SampleListFragment())
            .commit();

            //sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
            sm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            action = getSupportActionBar();
              // action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
              // action.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

               action.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

               action.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#343333")));
             //  action.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#66ffffff")));
               action.setIcon(R.drawable.menu);
             //  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
              // action.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);

           // getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(
          //          R.layout.actionbar);
           // action.setIcon(R.drawable.menu);

          //  getActionBar().setIcon(
                      // new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 

          //  action.setCustomView(view);







    }




    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
             sm.toggle();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}






public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class SampleItem {
        public String tag;
        public int iconRes;
        public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
            this.tag = tag; 
            this.iconRes = iconRes;
        }
    }

    public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

        public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
            icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:id="@+id/lin"

     >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a container for the fragment to replace it . You can use a frame layout for the container like this-

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You can add your fragment by the fragment transaction to this container if your activity is set to have this xml layout or fragment is inflated with the layout containing the frame layout/container.

Then you can use the code-

```
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, new SampleListFragment())
        .commit();
```

If you are looking for a Navigation Drawer type Activity then using DrawerLayout is good option. You can have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: Why you are looking for the fragment?
You are using the library already having the lsit view in the drawer side.?
Where are adding the another fragment as list?

Answer (score 0):

NOOO! the list.xml should be the view layout you return to the fragment as its rootview

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container);
}
```

and this code `.replace(R.id.i_am_suppose_to_refer_t0_a_viewgroup(LinearLayout or something), new SampleListFragment())` in your `activity_main.xml` layout file.. check the docs for more info